# Issue using i18n_patterns with API

Tags: django, url-pattern

I have an app which includes a website and an API. I have translated the website to a second language. The main language is currently English and the second one Farsi. I have used `i18n_patterns` in `urlpatterns` to redirect between the two languages. 
**The issue is** when using the API, it seems like Django redirects my request and since the data is sent using `POST`, it drops all data and gives me an empty result using `GET`. I tried taking the API url out of the urlpattern and then appending it which solves this issue, but that doesn't work since I need to have Unicode support for Farsi and since there is no `i18n_patterns` support this way, I get an unintelligible response.
This is the Urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('mainapp/', include('mainapp.urls')),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=True
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns.append(path('api/', include('mainapp.api.urls')))
```

Is there any way I can solve this issue with the least possible change to the app? Any help, suggestion, or guidance would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thank you. I changed the code to reproduce the issue. I call `http://localhost:8000/api/scan/`. If I add the `path('api/', include('mainapp.api.urls'))` to the original urlpattern with `i18n_patterns`, and send the request to API, the `request.POST` value is `<QueryDict: {}>` while otherwise it should send a `key:value` to the backend. I looked around and it seems when you add `i18n_patterns` to urlpatterns, a redirect happens and since HTTP doesn't allow POST data redirects, I get an empty response.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a redirect. You should explain exactly what url you're calling, what causes the redirect, and what url the redirect is to. Use explicit urls please (path/to/something).

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer to explain the problem better.

Comment: But you should not send the request to `/api/scan/` at all if you're expecting requests to be sent in the correct language. You should send to `<lang>/api/scan/` so you don't get a redirect. Alternatively, you can set `prefix_default_language` to `False` so that the English urls aren't prefix and hence a request to `/api/scan` will be assumed to be English and not redirected.

Comment: Note that I also don't understand why you get a wrong response if you don't use the translated url patterns. Django does not detect the language based solely on the url pattern, it detects it based on the headers or cookie, look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). If you don't need your urls to be translated (and in an API it rarely makes sense to do that), then I would not include my API urls in i18n_patterns. Just ensure the requests to your api contain the correct HTTP header.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you. I have no idea why this is happening. I don't even know what to search for. Though, to circumvent the problem somehow, I changed my urlpattern settings to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('sslcheck.api.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sslcheck/', include('sslcheck.urls')),
    path('', include('sslcheck.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=True,
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```
Now is there a way to force only the API to load in English?

Comment: You should read the translation page I linked above. All of it. You clearly don't understand what i18n_patterns is supposed to do: It's only to translate the url itself. So for example if you have a url /shop/product/ in english and you want it to be /magazin/produit/ in french so your users get a better understanding of where they are on the site (when they look at the address bar in their browser).

Comment: @dirkgroten Uh. Thanks. I might have misunderstood the docs. I did try to read them though. I'm very new to programming. If you put this in the answers. I will choose it as the right solution.

Comment: Take your API urls out of the the i18n_patterns and fix the original issue you're trying to solve, which is the "unintelligible response". Set the HTTP header for Accept-Language to Farsi in your POST request and if you still have a wrong response, submit a new question on that if you're stuck.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have taken the URL for API out of i18n_patterns. That solves the POST/GET issue. Though I still get it in Farsi because the default language settings are in 'fa'. I need the site to load in Farsi, but not the API.

Comment: Then set the HTTP Accept-Language to English for all your API requests. And check that the cookie isn't set (it looks for the cookie first). Also, you can override the language manually in your code for all your API views if you want to ensure that whoever calls the API always gets English.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you very much for all the help. I will look for these. I hope I can fix it. I would like to accept your answer, if you please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of `i18n_patterns` is to **translate the url itself**, so it's a bit weird that you'd want to that for an API. The idea is that users who look at the address bar in their browser read the urls and it might help to translate them so it's easier for them to understand where they are on your site. So for example if you have a url "/shop/product/" in English and you want it to be "/magazin/produit/" in French.

Since an API doesn't display URLs to end-users, it just doesn't make sense to have the API urls fall under `i18n_patterns`. That will solve the redirect issue.

Your original problem is that your view returns an "unintelligible response" when you call it using an URL which doesn't specify the language. That's probably because the view is detecting the wrong language. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) is how Django detects the language preference. So if the url doesn't have the information, it will:

- Look for the language cookie.
- Look at the Accept-Language HTTP header, in this order.

So you can either ensure your API requests set the correct header (and don't send the language cookie), or you can just [set the active language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) in each view called by the API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It made things much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your problem fully, but you can prevent the redirects by setting `redirect_on_fallback` to `False` in your `CMS_LANGUAGES` settings.